# Segmentation fault i cant figure out

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have the following constructor:

```
    Timing::Timing():
    _numMes(INIT_NUMMES),_msgs(new allMSgs*[NUMBER_OF_MSGS])
    {

        cout<<"build timing OK\n";
    }
```

allMSgs is a struct :

```
   typedef struct AllMSgs
   {
            double msg;
        Agent* dedicatedTo;
   }allMSgs;
```

and the declaration of it is done like this:

```
        allMSgs** _msgs;
```

but when i try to reach for a field in the array like this:

```
     _msgs[loc]->dedicatedTo=agent->getPointsTo();
```

i get a segmentation fault.

NUMBER_OF_MSGS is 1000

loc is 0,1,2.... (less then 1000);

help please

Comment: Okay. I am just a little lost here. Are you trying to access a double star pointer without it actually pointing to any specific allocated section of memory? Because if you are, this would explain why it's crashing.

Comment: Not an answer to your question (and hence a comment), but avoid allocating resources in the initializer list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've made an array of pointers, but not set them to point anywhere valid yet. You *either* need to change it to be simply:

```
allMSgs* _msgs;
```

and:

```
new allMSgs[NUMBER_OF_MSGS]
```

Or call new for each pointer in the `allMSgs` array.

Better yet though you could just use a `std::vector` or other container, with `std::vector<allMSgs> _msgs;`, which you can use like it was an array in most cases. You can initalise it with a size too.

Answer (score 1):

You have only allocated the array itself. You need to allocate each and every item of the array too. In the constructor, add a `for` loop that allocates all of the items.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MSGS; i++)
  _msgs[i] = new allMSgs();
```

You can also just define the array as an array of `allMSgs` and not pointers to `allMSgs`.

```
allMSgs* _msgs;
```